# Computing a target number from a set of natural numbers

Tags: optimization, computer-science, computational-complexity, computational-mathematics, discrete-optimization

Given a set of natural numbers $S=\{n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_m\}$ and a target number $n$, the goal is to compute the target number using only elemental operations, namely $+,-,*,/,(,)$ and numbers from $S$. A second goal would be to minimize the numbers to be used from $S$. Numbers from $S$ can be taken more than once but each extra copy counts towards the number of numbers used.

Of course one way would be to brute force it but the number of computations get wild pretty fast. I was hoping to get some pointers on how to do this more efficiently or if impossible, a way to get 'good' (near the minimum) solutions.

Comment: There should be some conditions for the S set, such as having at least two relative prime numbers. If so, you can use Euclid's algorithm to obtain 1. Afterwards, any number can be obtained from 1. In practice, to reduce the amount of operations you would want to use some multiplication that gets you close to your target number, but this would likely require non-elementary operations to directly find the bets set of numbers. In summary, sounds like a fun game, but also seems like an ill-posed problem

Comment: Yeah I think we can assume that getting to the target number will not be an issue. I did think of approaching the number with products if the target is big, but I wondered if there is  way to find the exact minimum. It does seem ill-posed to me too though.